# ValueError:not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Tags: python, python-3.x

On python3.6,
(my dataset graph.txt is like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO6JW.png)))

and each line split by \t

**My code:**

```
   text_file, graph_file = self.load(text_path, graph_path)

   self.edges = self.load_edges(graph_file)

def load(self, text_path, graph_path):
    text_file = open(text_path, 'rb').readlines()
    graph_file = open(graph_path, 'rb').readlines()
    return text_file, graph_file

def load_edges(self, graph_file):
    edges = []
    for i in graph_file:
        edges.append(map(int, i.strip().decode("utf-8").split('\t')))
    return edges
```

however when i run below function :

```
def negative_sample(self, edges):
    node1, node2 = zip(*edges)
    sample_edges = []
    func = lambda:self.negative_table[random.randint(0,config.neg_table_size - 1)]
    for i in range(len(edges)):
        neg_node = func()
        while node1[i] == neg_node or node2[i] == neg_node:neg_node = func()
        sample_edges.append([node1[i], node2[i], neg_node])
    return sample_edges
```

**Error:**

> value error:In function:negative_sample node1, node2 = zip(*edges)
>
> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Comment: `node1, node2 = zip(*edges)` doesn't look right. You should review what `zip()` does.

Comment: please, post your data sample as text

Comment: what exactly is in you `edges`

Comment: You might have an empty line in your file and need to filter it out.

Comment: my data sample look like this:
440 50
440 103
440 105
440 116
440 135
440 235
440 257
440 353
440 380
454 255
454 404
511 440
511 471
511 478
519 105
519 353
519 440
519 478
519 511
584 478
584 511
584 539
693 116
693 475
693 584

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this question. In python2 ,map return a list but for python3.x， map ruturn a iterable,so the code should change like :

```
   edges.append(list(map(int, i.strip().decode("utf-8").split('\t'))))
```